# INSTALLING UBUNTU 12.04 fro already downloaded file (installing with pendrive)

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, usb-drive, downloads

I have got this file downloaded:

```
ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I have a 64 bit OS and want to install ubuntu 12.04 on it alongside win 7 (which I already ahve on the PC)

I have a Pendrive. how do I install ubuntu using the already downloaded file (given above) and a pendrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download [ubootnetin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and turn a USB drive into a bootable install media.  Then, go into your BIOS settings and set it to boot from USB,  With the USB plugged in, boot the system and install.  I do not know if you have used Linux before, but once you install Ubuntu, you will be using the Grub bootloader to boot into Windows.  Keep that in mind and save your Ubuntu install media so you can use it as a rescue disk should Windows overwrite the MBR as it is sometimes wont to do.

Comment: thanx ChrisR 4 dat.. I just nw tried the same but isn't it possible to select usb for booting rather than setting it as the default boot option?? ma bios doesn't change any settings.. it says it has a password...

Comment: If you unplug the power cable and remove the CMOS battery for 2-5 minutes and then put  it back in, it will automatically reset the BIOS to the default settings and also remove the BIOS password.

Comment: didn't work... It took lot of time to search for the cmos battery location but I did that.. It did not work... is it still necessary to set the "usb" as default boot option? or I can just choose it from list as temporary optioin??

Comment: The way I do it is to set USB-HDD to be first in the BIOS Boot Device Priority list and then I change it back after I'm finished with it. But not being able to get into the BIOS at all could be a problem, although there are some big questions on Superuser Q&A about how to solve that problem.

Comment: Abhay, there is usually a button (depending on manufacturer) that you can press during startup that will bring up a menu to select the boot drive.  It is usually F9-F11.